# Apache site application authenticate to IIS Laserfiche CMIS Gateway application

Tags: javascript, apache, iis, cmis

Not even sure how to explain this correctly.

We have a custom ERP application written in PHP/Javascript running in Apache,  we also  have a Laserfiche Server running a CMIS gateway in IIS.  We need to be able pass the authentication from the ERP application running in Apache to The IIS Laserfiche CMIS.  Can someone explain how this might work?

Comment: you could try to use iis reverse proxy for Tomcat. Configure IIS to use Windows authentication. Configure Tomcat to use the authentication user information from IIS by setting the tomcatAuthentication attribute on the AJP connector to false. Alternatively, set the tomcatAuthorization attribute to true to allow IIS to authenticate, while Tomcat performs the authorization.for more detail you could refer this link: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/windows-auth-howto.html

Comment: Is your issue solved?